# select text inside h1 - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, select, text

Hi Im trying select the text inside my h1 title. My code:

```
<html>
    <h1 id="myText">TextToSelect</h1>
</html>

<script>
    var text = document.getElementById("myText");
    text.select();
</script>
```

example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyBi8.png)

Comment: Excuse me, I suppose you express me wrong. I just want to select the text. Update the post and add an example photo.

Comment: Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyBi8.png

Comment: I dont try to get the text, only select, 
as if I did it with the mouse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such function called `select()` in the [HTMLElement Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createRange)

To simulate user selection, You can try this :

```js
var element = document.querySelector('#myText');
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNode(element);
window.getSelection().addRange(range);
```

```html
<h1 id="myText">TextToSelect</h1>
```

For more Info Visit the MDN Documentation on the  [Range Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createRange)

Comment: Excuse me, I suppose you express me wrong. I just want to select the text. Update the post and add an example photo.

Comment: I dont try to get the text, only select, as if I did it with the mouse

Answer (score 0):

there is no select to get the text, with this:

```
var h1Element = document.getElementById("myText");
```

you get the reference to your h1 tag in the DOM, but to extract the value select doesn't work, use innerText

**like this:**

```
h1Element.innerText;
```